# Order Submission Magento

Tags: magento

We have a strange problem on Magento.

A customer added 50 products on cart, clicked on "Proceed to Checkout", confirmed Shipping and Payment Method and then he confirmed the order.

The problem is that there is a .gif that shows "loading" and a message that told the user to wait but nothing happens.

The strange thing is that the order is not submitted but products quantity are unloaded from database.

Two interesting aspects:

1) If I separate the big order into 3 small orders there aren't problems.

2) I can see only one error on PHP Log (but I am not sure that it's related to this):

> [23-Jan-2013 06:54:28] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/**************/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 655
>   [23-Jan-2013 09:23:08] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/**************/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 1003
>   [23-Jan-2013 11:38:17] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/**************/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 961
>   [23-Jan-2013 11:43:40] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/**************/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 654

Thanks

Comment: I think magento tries to refresh the chaches. And this is soo time consuming, that he hits the max_execution_time. APC might help. You can think about changing the Cache backend, but afaik is File the fallback, so you need to disable this. I'm not sure wether this is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

This very much have to do with the speed of your server. You could rise the execution time in your php.ini, but the very problem is the speed. 30 seconds looks like too much for me.

Maybe an APC cache could speed this webshop enough for the webshop to handle such large orders.

Comment: What do you mean for APC cache?

Thanks.